# Open another port on client machine

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, applet

Can I create a web application that can open a port on client machine make it listen for incoming connections. Is there any way to achieve this possibility ?

Comment: An open port is anyway useless unless some code is running behind that port.  I think you need to clarify your question

Comment: Want to connect to open port and want to create a scenario like server is querying client.

Comment: You want to do something like "server push"?

Comment: No the scenario is like, web application which is running on port-80
will have ability to open a port on client machine and make it listening for connections it may sound vague, but this is scenario i want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve it by Applet/JWS and socket program. The applet should have permission(signed) to use the system resources.

However the concern is that the firewall running on the client machine might block it.